# How can I debug `Unable to submit changelist due to an unknown error`?

Tags: perforce

```
SubmitChangeList Failed!
Unable to submit changelist due to an unknown error, please check the detailed text.
```

The detailed text is just a list of files that don't seem to be related in any way. There is markdown, binaries, man pages, yaml, etc. I'm pushing a 3rd party app into the depot.

What steps can I take to find out more about the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the submit from the command line.

`SubmitChangeList Failed!` isn't a Perforce error message, so I surmise that there is some sort of tool in between you and `p4 submit`, and that tool is helpfully mangling the error message to prevent you from debugging the problem.  Eliminate the middleman and you should get something more helpful.

Comment: There was an internal tool in between me and Perforce.